# Replace spaces from string in href

Tags: php, string, replace, preg-replace, spaces

How can I replace spaces in a href with %20?

I allready got this: (It is replacing not only the spaces in the href attribute)

```
function callback($string){
$string = substr($string,0, -2);
$string = substr($string, 9);
$string = preg_replace('/\s+/','%20',$string);
$string = '<a href="'.$string.'">';
return $string;
}
$suchen = '(<a href="(.*?)">)s';
echo preg_replace_callback($suchen,create_function('$treffer','return callback($treffer[0]);'),$new7);
```

"$new7" is the old string.

Comment: `$string = preg_replace('/\s+/','%20',$string);` can probably just be `$string = str_replace(' ','%20',$string);`

Comment: @JohnConde this works too, but thats not the reason why other spaces are replaced

Comment: @qwertz1029384756: What exactly isn't working? Could you show us an example of a URL that isn't working as expected?

Comment: @AmalMurali     <a href="ts3server://xxxx?port=10194&amp;channel=|%20AFK%20|"%20>|%20AFK%20|</a>&nbsp;</div><div%20style="float:right">     it keeps replacing the spaces

Comment: @qwertz1029384756: Is that not what you're trying to do (replace spaces?)

Comment: @AmalMurali ...Only in the href attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your href attribute is always quoted, you can use this pattern:

```
$pattern = '~(?>\bhref\s*=\s*["\']|\G(?<!^))[^ "\']*+\K ~';
$result = preg_replace($pattern, '%20', $html);
```

pattern details:

```
~
(?>                     # open an atomic group (*)
    \bhref\s*=\s*["\']  # attribute name until the quote
  |                     # OR
    \G(?<!^)            # contiguous to a precedent match
)                       # close the atomic group
[^ "\']*+               # content that is not a space or quotes (optional) 
\K                      # resets the start of the match from match result
[ ]                     # a space
~
```

*(*) An [atomic group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) is a non-capturing group where the regex engine is not allowed to  backtrack.*

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to make the string url-safe, the preferred method is using [`urlencode()`](https://www.php.net/urlencode) to replace spaces with %20 and other nasty things. From the example [in the documentation](https://www.php.net/urlencode):

```
echo '<a href="mycgi?foo=', urlencode($userinput), '">';
```

Comment: +1 for `urlencode()`, however, I'm not sure the OP has an access to `$userinput` in the present case.